# Error in Auto wiring component

Tags: spring, autowired

I am getting a weird issue while using @Autowired annotation

I am injecting one spring component into another spring component like below

```
import com.myutil.GenericUtils;
@Component
public class MyDomainImpl implements MyDomain {
    @Autowired
    private GenericUtils genericUtils;
}
```

and this works fine

When I  try to inject the same component a different component ( which is implementing a generic interface ) , it throws the below error.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The argument does not represent an annotation type: Autowired**

This is the code which throws the error

```
import com.myutil.GenericUtils;
@Component
public class MyMapper implements GenericMapper<Mycomponent,MycomponentSO>{
    @Autowired
    private GenericUtils genericUtils;
}
```

I am seeing this error first time using Spring FW.
 I tried to find out the root cause , but no luck.

If I remove the autowiring , the compilation error does not occur

In case if anybody has faced this error, please advise the solution

Thanks

Lives

Comment: Do you have something else (a class or an interface) that is named `Autowired` which you are accidentally importing instead of Spring's `Autowired` annotation?

Comment: Did you import the correct package for @Autowired

Comment: Pakaj -  You saved my day . thanks  a lot.  I did not import the right Autowried Class. In fact I did not import the Autowired class at all. Instead of throwing a compilation error , the class got picked up from some where in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in auto-wiring MyMapper not auto-wiring GenericUtils, if you are auto-wiring it using interface GenericMapper try to change it to MyMapper as:

```
@Autowired
private GenericMapper myMapper ;
```

to

```
@Autowired
private MyMapper myMapper ;
```

if it is working so mostly you have a proxy wrapping your bean.

**Update:**

after re review the error again I found it is most probably coming from java it self, specially from `RoundEnvironment` it have `getElementsAnnotatedWith` and this method is throw exception as

> IllegalArgumentException - if the argument does not represent an
>   annotation type

which is your case which is meaning that it is not considering Autowired as annotation type so please check if you have any other class with name Autowired may it is imported wrongly, or you have some missing jars in your build.

Comment: Actually I also suspected the same issue . But the issue was not in auto wiring of GenericMapper. Even when I try as per the code you suggested , it gives the same error.